shinyjs::show/hide & observeEvent when the last selected item is removed
This is a follow-up to a previous question.
I now wish to add an action button "Clear" that is only shown when there are actually items selected. Here is my code, where I try to use shinyjs:
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), # needed for hidden/show
    shiny::selectizeInput(
        inputId="letters", 
        label="Restrict to Letters:",
        choices=letters, 
        selected=NULL,
        multiple = TRUE,
        options=list(
            placeholder="(all letters)"
        )
    ),
    shinyjs::hidden(actionButton("clear","Clear")) # start hidden
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$clear, {
        updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "letters", selected= "")
        shinyjs::hide(id="clear")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$letters, { # is not called if the last selected item is removed
        if(shiny::isTruthy(input$letters)) {
            message("length(input$letters)=", length(input$letters))
            shinyjs::show(id="clear")
        } else { # no filter
            message("hiding clear button from oe(input$letters)")
            shinyjs::hide(id="clear")
        }
    })

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)

The code has still one problems IMO: observeEvent(input$letters, ...) is not called when I deselect the last item.
That is, if I select some items and set hit the clear button, everything works as expected:
# Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5582
# length(input$letters)=1
# length(input$letters)=2
# length(input$letters)=3
# hiding clear button from oe(input$clear)

But if I select some items and then deselect them using the backspace key, the clear button stays visible:
# Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5582
# length(input$letters)=1
# length(input$letters)=2
# length(input$letters)=3
# length(input$letters)=2
# length(input$letters)=1
# (... and nothing else ...)


Hej Karsten. There is no input named subjects, i.e. try if(length(input$letters)>0). And it should be updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "letters", **selected = ""**, session)

Thanks, the example now works. However, I still don't  understand why never the message "length(input$letters)=0" appears...

I'd suggest using the remove_button plugin instead of creating a separate clear button: options = list(placeholder = "(all letters)", plugins = list('remove_button')),

Your message appears with message(paste0("length(input$letters)=", length(input$letters)))...  it's a typo. :-(

It seems still not to work here, see updated question. Updating shiny to 1.8.1.1 did not help either...

@ismirsehregal: the remove_button is nice, but I am looking for an option to remove all selected items.

Just for reference, I finally found a solution that works for me. Changing the server function to
server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$clear, {
        updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "letters", selected="")
    })
    
    no_filter <- shiny::reactive(!shiny::isTruthy(input$letters))
    
    observeEvent(input$letters, { # is not called if the last selected item is removed
        if(shiny::isTruthy(input$letters)) {
            message("length(input$letters)=", length(input$letters))
            shinyjs::show(id="clear")
        } 
    })
    
    observeEvent(no_filter(), {
        if(no_filter()) shinyjs::hide(id="clear")
    })
}

now hides the clear button as I intend it to.
